# What should I take into account when underclocking Intel i5-750?

Tags: underclock, undervolting

I'm using my PC at idle all the time. I want to underclock the CPU at these hot summer days.

I got into the BIOS screen, and I saw a setting for "CPU Clock Ratio". I reduced it from 21 to 9. After a reboot I saw that CPU temperature reduced from 6X<sup>o</sup>C to 4X<sup>o</sup>C. CPU fan became much more silent. Everything looks fine.

Is this only thing I should have done? Is there any other settings should I alter? Like CPU core voltages, memory settings, etc? When I browse the BIOS screens I become confused, because there are a lot of hardware terms and details that I don't know.

My hardware is listed below:

- CPU: Intel i5-750
- Mainboard: Gigabyte P55A-UD3R
- RAM: 2 x 2GB, DDR3, 1333MHz, CL7

I'm adding the relevant BIOS screens below:

## Main Screen

[image: Main Screen]
[*See Larger Version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwZD8.jpg)

---

## M.I.T Current Status

[image: M.I.T Current Status]
[*See Larger Version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI5Eg.jpg)

---

## Advanced Frequency Settings

[image: Advanced Frequency Settings]
[*See Larger Version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VghcR.jpg)

---

## Advanced Memory Settings

[image: Advanced Memory Settings]
[*See Larger Version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cch1k.jpg)

---

## Advanced Voltage Settings

[image: Advanced Voltage Settings]
[*See Larger Version*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2U03.jpg)

Comment: Voltage is the primary factor that determines CPU temperature, however I wouldn't recommend changing it if you're not experienced/have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: what you have changed is called the multiplier. The base clock speed of your CPU is probably 133Mhz which was multiplied by 21 before (~2.8Ghz) and is now multiplied by 9 (~1.2Ghz). What you did is fairly safe and will just make your computer run slower. "Real" underclocking is done by changing the voltage of the CPU. Less voltage means less power use, means less heat etc.